# Grails - using property value for cron expression in scheduled job

Tags: grails, cron, quartz-scheduler

Am using the Quartz plugin for Grails and have a simple job:

```
class MyJob{

   static triggers = {
       cron name: 'MyJobTrigger', cronExpression: '0 0/1 * * * ?'
   }
   def execute(){
       println "do some work"
   }
}
```

All works fine, job fires off every minute as expected.

Now I want the want the cron expression to be property driven so I can override in different environments. So Config.groovy contains the default value:

```
myJob.cron = '0 0/1 * * * * ?'
```

And I change my class to have:

```
   GrailsApplication grailsApplication

   static triggers = {
       cron name: 'MyJobTrigger', cronExpression: grailsApplication.config.myJob.cron
   }
```

When I run my code, I get this error:

```
Caused by MissingPropertyException: No such property: grailsApplication for class: MyJob
```

Assuming this is something to do with the way the MyJob class is loaded/initialised, the static triggers created before the GrailsApplication is injected??? This use of GrailsApplication is the usual way I get project properties.

How else can I have a property driven cron trigger?

Comment: That does appear to work, but ConfigurationHolder is marked as deprecated with a comment of 'Use dependency injection instead'. Any suggestions on what the alternative is?

Comment: Use `def grailsApplication` and `grailsApplication.config...` as you were, but in bootstrap

Answer (score 3):

I *just* ran into this, and adding the scheduling to Bootstrap.groovy worked just fine. In your MyJob class, set triggers to an empty closure:

```
class MyJob {

   static triggers = {
        // Job is scheduled in Bootstrap.groovy so that it can be externalized
    }

   def execute() {
       println "do some work"
   }
}
```

Then in your Bootstrap.groovy file, set it up like this:

```
class BootStrap {

    def grailsApplication

    def init = { servletContext ->
        MyJob.schedule(grailsApplication.config.myJob.cron)
    }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work. I get a 'no property MyJob for class BootStrap' runtime error. Even if I What plugin are you using? I've just got the quartz 1.0-RC9. MyJob is a groovy class under grails-app/jobs/myApp, which is where the plugin's create-job command creates it.

Comment: Be sure to import that class at the top of Bootstrap.groovy. The schedule method is static, so you should call it using the class name (with a capital first letter, assuming you named the class with a capital letter). Also, I am using the same plugin and version you are. Quartz 1.9-RC9.

Comment: i tried your method but on bootstrap its shows an error( no such property myjob).on importing class job on bootstrap compiler showing a red line